# R: Update Column Based on Text Condition from Another Column

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to make a new column in my data frame by using a conditional statement that would say "If Column_y contains Column_x then 1 else 0"

For example:

```
Event   Name     Winner       Loser          New Column
1       James    James,Bob    John,Steve     1
1       Bob      James,Bob    John,Steve     1
1       John     James,Bob    John,Steve     0
1       Steve    James,Bob    John,Steve     0
```

I want to have New Column<- "If Winner contains Name then 1 else 0"

Keep in mind this is for 100,000 rows and probably 700 unique names.  When I try things like

```
df$NewColumn<-ifelse(grepl(df$Name,df$Winner)==TRUE,1,0)
```

or variations I get the "pattern has a length > 1" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, exact string matching works. But I am assuming it does not hold true for your entire data.

Implementing the contains condition would be something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df = df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(NewColumn = purrr::map2_dbl(.x=Winner,.y=Name,~ifelse(grepl(.y,.x),1,0)))
```

Adding an alternate solution with `stringr`:

```
df = df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(NewColumn=ifelse(str_detect(Winner,Name),1,0))
```

Let me know if this works.

P.S.: `str_detect` is faster.

Comment: Thank you so much makeshift this definitely worked!  I have no idea what any of it means but it gave me the desired result!

Comment: I realize purrr syntax takes a little getting used to. Also, you could alternatively use ```str_detect``` from ```stringr``` package. The syntax is: ```df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(NewColumn=ifelse(str_detect(Winner,Name),1,0))```. Note the change in argument positions as compared to grepl.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to compare the `Name` column against the `Winner` column:

```
df$NewColumn <- ifelse(df$Name == df$Winner, 1, 0)
```

Note that because `df$Name == df$Winner` is actually a boolean expression, you might also be able to simplify to:

```
df$NewColumn <- df$Name == df$Winner
```

Comment: Sorry I realized an error in my example as your answer tells me exactly what I would need if the "Winner" and "Loser" columns just had the name and that is it.  I failed to mention that there is another component and that the "Winner" and "Loser" columns have multiple names.  I will edit the question as such but think of it as a multi-person competition and the data comes through with multiple names in the Winner or Loser columns but I want to assign a 1 or 0 for each name.